# Flash CS4: Rotate object clockwise or counterclockwise

Tags: flash, object, rotation

Is there way to control the movieclip rotation direction - clockwise or counterclockwise? I mean no actionscript, just timeline and mouse. I have two almost identical movieclips on two layers, and need both of them to rotate in one direction, but one rotates clockwise and the other counterclockwise. I tried clicking and rotating objects in motion tween, even deleting and creating new instances of them from the library, but I still have no idea what is the principle of how Flash "chooses" the rotation direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the direction of the tween's rotation in the [motion propery inspector](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/motion_migration_guide_05.html).